# Duplicate planning entities in the solution

Tags: java, optaplanner, constraint-programming

I'm new to Optaplanner, and I try to solve a quite simple problem (for now, I will add more constraints eventually).
My model is the following: I have tasks (`MarkerNesting`), that must run one at a time on a `VirtualMachine`; the goal is to assign a list of `MarkerNesting`s to `VirtualMachine`s, having all machines used (we can consider that we have more tasks than machines as a first approximation). As a result, I expect each task to have a start and a end date (as shadow variables - not implemented yet).

I think I must use a chained variable, with the `VirtualMachine` being the anchor (chained through time pattern) - am I right?

So I wrote a [program](https://github.com/cdelmas/scheduler-poc) inspired by some examples (tsp and coach and shuttle) with 4 machines and 4 tasks, and I expect each machine having one task when it is solved. When running it, though, I get some strange results : not all machines are used, but the worst is that I have duplicate `MarkerNesting` instances (output example):

```
[VM 1/56861999]~~~>[Nesting(155/2143571436)/[Marker m4/60s]]~~~>[Nesting(816/767511741)/[Marker m2/300s]]~~~>[Nesting(816/418304857)/[Marker m2/300s]]~~~>[Nesting(980/1292472219)/[Marker m1/300s]]~~~>[Nesting(980/1926764753)/[Marker m1/300s]]
[VM 2/1376400422]~~~>[Nesting(155/1815546035)/[Marker m4/60s]]
[VM 3/1619356001]
[VM 4/802771878]~~~>[Nesting(111/548795052)/[Marker m3/180s]]
```

The instances are different (to read the log: `[Nesting(id/hashcode)]`), but they have the same id, so they are the same entity in the end. If I understand well, Optaplanner clones the solution whenever it finds a best one, but I don't know why it mixes instances like that.

Is there anything wrong in my code? Is it a normal behavior?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate MarkerNesting instances that you didn't create, have the same content, but a different memory address, so are `!=` from each other: that means something when wrong in the default solution cloner, which is based on reflection. It's been a while since anyone ran into an issue there. See docs section on "planning clone". The complex model of chained variables (which [will be improved](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/PLANNER/issues/PLANNER-239)) doesn't help here at all.

Sometimes a well placed `@DeepPlanningClone` fixes it, but in this case it might as well be due to the `@InverseRelationShadowVariable` not being picked.

In any case, those `system.out`'s in the setter method are misleading - they can happen both by the solution cloner as well as by the moves, so without the solution hash (= memory address), they tell nothing. Try doing a similar system.out in either your best solution change events, or in the `BestSolutionRecaller` call to `cloneWorkingSolution()`, for both the original as well as the clone.

Comment: Do comment when you find the actual cause! That way I can maybe make OptaPlanner detect it on booting.

Comment: Not sure it is related, but I get an exception when running in NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT mode: see the stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/cdelmas/065ee6f3b3dab4b222976b3f9e3f9951).

Furthermore, I added an event listener to the solver, so that when I get a best solution I can log it (but I cannot get the old one) ; the solution after the first move is still ok, but the next ones are corrupted.

Comment: FULL_ASSERT should also give that exception. The initial solution passed to `Solver.solve(...)` has a next that is inconsistent, so it is corrupted.

Comment: You are right, I initialize a solution with all tasks on the same machine, so there are next that are `null` (on all the other `VirtualMachine`s).

Answer (score 1):

As expected, I was doing something wrong: in `Schedule` (the `PlanningSolution`), I had a getter for a collection of `VirtualMachine`, which calculate from another field (`pools` : each `Pool` holds `VirtualMachine`s). As a result, there where no setter, and the solution cloner was probably not able to clone the solution properly (maybe because `pools` is not annotated as a problem fact or a planning entity?).

To fix the problem, I removed the `Pool` class (not really needed), leaving a collection of `VirtualMachine`s in `Schedule`.

To sum up, never introduce too many classes before you need them ^_^'

I pushed the correct version of my code on github.

Comment: The solution cloner looks at the fields, not the getters. But this does explain it: For some reason, the VirtualMachine classes are planning cloned (they contain a genuine or a shadow variable or point to an entity class), but the solution cloner didn't go into the pool class, so it only replaced the references in those. The solution was to @DeepPlanningClone the pools field in solution.

Comment: Ok, so I will try this too. Maybe I will need it eventually, it's good to know that. Thank you!

Comment: It does work with a `@DeepPlanningClone` on the `Pool` class, but not on the field.

Comment: Hmm, it should: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/domain/solution/cloner/FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java#L196 . That sounds like a bug. If you're sure it's like that, please create a jira.

Comment: I can reproduce it at will. I created a jira: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1481